# Conventions for naming mutable/immutable API functions?

Tags: rust, naming-conventions

When writing APIs, it's common to have a mutable and an immutable version of a method.

I expected the standard library to have clear conventions about how to name these, but it's not totally consistent<sup>1</sup>:

What are good naming conventions for the following methods?

```
pub fn foo****(&self) -> &Bar { ... }
pub fn foo****(&mut self) -> &mut Bar { ... }
```

- `foo()` | `foo_mut()`

  This seems the most common, and can be seen in `Vec.iter` and `Vec.iter_mut`.
- `foo_ref()` | `foo_mut()`

  Used for `Any.downcast_ref` and `Any.downcast_mut`.

It seems the first case is more common, so what are the reasons for using the `_ref` suffix when naming API functions?

---

**1**: It is probably consistent and I'm just failing to notice the reasoning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, conventions for this are defined in [RFC 199](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0199-ownership-variants.md). The important part is:

> ### The rules
>
> #### Immutably borrowed by default
>
> If `foo` uses/produces an immutable borrow by default, use:
>
> - The `_mut` suffix (e.g. `foo_mut`) for the mutably borrowed variant.
> - The `_move` suffix (e.g. `foo_move`) for the owned variant.
>
> However, in the case of iterators, the moving variant can also be understood as an `into` conversion, `into_iter`, and `for x in v.into_iter()` reads arguably better than `for x in v.iter_move()`, so the convention is `into_iter`.
>
> **NOTE**: This convention covers only the *method* names for   iterators, not the names of the iterator types. That will be the subject of a follow up RFC.
>
> #### Owned by default
>
> If `foo` uses/produces owned data by default, use:
>
> - The `_ref` suffix (e.g. `foo_ref`) for the immutably borrowed variant.
> - The `_mut` suffix (e.g. `foo_mut`) for the mutably borrowed variant.

---

`Any::downcast_ref` isn't called `downcast` because there is a method named `downcast` on [`Box<Any + 'static>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.downcast) and on [`Box<Any + 'static + Send>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.downcast-1) that takes `self` by value. Naming the method on `Any` `downcast` would cause one to shadow the other. So the whole picture is:

- `downcast`, takes `self`, defined on [`Box<Any + 'static>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.downcast) and [`Box<Any + 'static + Send>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.downcast-1)
- `downcast_ref`, takes `&self`, defined on [`Any + 'static`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/trait.Any.html#method.downcast_ref) and [`Any + 'static + Send`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/trait.Any.html#method.downcast_ref-1)
- `downcast_mut`, takes `&mut self`, defined on [`Any + 'static`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/trait.Any.html#method.downcast_mut) and [`Any + 'static + Send`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/trait.Any.html#method.downcast_mut-1)